# Prevent jquery Pagination href Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm using the jquery Pagination Plugin that is provided [here](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/#demo) and am trying to pass the number of the page clicked to a function

```
$('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
        totalPages: 35,
        visiblePages: 7,
        href: '?page={{number}}',
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            event.preventDefault(); //Trying to disable the href redirect
            search(page);
        }
    });
```

The `href` attribute appentds the page number to the pagination anchor tags, however I don't want to redirect when these anchors are selected (I assumed the callback function would be able to prevent this) - I want to call my search method asynchronously and pass the `{number}` value. Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because I'm up too late, but the answer was sitting right in front of my face. The second argument passed in the `onPageClick` callback ***IS*** the value I'm looking for (the number of the page selected).